# I am getting no data found error in pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am getting no data found error in pl/sql
Actually problem is in the trigger
I want to use NO_DATA_FOUND error in the elsif statement

```
alter table SUPPLIER  add  trusted_supplier VARCHAR(30)
```

and then update it with the data that I load in the table

```
UPDATE SUPPLIER SET   trusted_supplier ='Exotic Liquids'
```

while using the select statement I have only one value in the trusted_supplier so if insert value in the product is not equal to that
trusted supplier value I am getting error as no data found
is there any way i use NO_DATA_FOUND error which is predefined in pl/sql in the else if statement

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CHECK_SUPPLIER
BEFORE INSERT ON PRODUCT

FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE
supplier_info varchar(400);
 except1 exception;
begin

select SUPPLIER_NAME
INTO supplier_info
FROM PRODUCT P JOIN SUPPLIER S
ON S.COMPANY_NAME = P.SUPPLIER_NAME
where S.trusted_supplier = :NEW.SUPPLIER_NAME ; here

if(supplier_info = 'Exotic Liquids') then
dbms_output.put_line('trusted supplier')
elsif 
---------here 

END IF;

exception
when except1 then
dbms_output.put_line('its not the trusted supplier');
END;
/
```

Comment: There is no column `SUPPLIER_NAME` in the table `SUPPLIER` on which the trigger is. You may have meant `COMPANY_NAME`.

Comment: IF you are going to check. if new value is Exotic Liquids or not why not use it like that ?
if(:NEW.TRUSTED_SUPPLIER != 'Exotic Liquids') then
raise except1;
END IF;

Comment: The query doesn't need to join to PRODUCT (and attempting to query it in a trigger on PRODUCT will fail anyway) - you can query SUPPLIER directly. Then if you included the supplier name check in the query you could use the predefined NO_DATA_FOUND exception in place of EXCEPT1. (Numbered variable names aren't a great approach anyway. A meaningful name would be better.) Or, don't use any named exception and use `raise_application_error` instead.

Comment: See my reply to your [later question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69135978/how-to-create-a-pl-sql-row-trigger-that-validates-a-column-from-another-table)